# CSS vertical middle border

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, linear-gradients

I'm trying to achieve the following using CSS: (focus on the middle part of the photo)

[image: screenshot]

My first attempt was something like:

```
<div style="background:blue;height:200px"></div>
<div style="background: linear-gradient(blue 50%, #ffffff 50%);>
    <img...><img...><img...>
</div>
```

But then I have no way to create the colored line in the middle.
(Correct me if I'm wrong?)

I assume a better way would be to create a 50% height div, and then creating a floating div for the photos.

I use bootstrap which is not great for vertical align, so I tried using this [FlexBox](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/).

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This tutorial has all the gradients you need: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify more than one background image (including gradients) for one element, e.g.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #006;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(to right, #f00, #ff0 25%, #0f0 50%, #0ff 75%, #00f),
        linear-gradient(to top, #fff, #fff),
        radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 39%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.7) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 59%,        
        rgba(255,255,255,.4) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 79%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 99%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%),
        radial-gradient(circle closest-side at center,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 39%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.7) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,.7) 59%,        
        rgba(255,255,255,.4) 60%, rgba(255,255,255,.4) 79%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,.1) 99%,
        rgba(255,255,255,.0) 100%);
    background-size: 100% 4px, 100% 50%, 62.5% auto, 62.5% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0 50%, 100% 50%;
}
```